# Evaluate $\displaystyle-\int e^{2x}\sin(e^{x})\ dx$

Tags: integration

$$-\int e^{2x}\sin(e^{x})\ dx$$

I've tried to use integration by parts but the integral is getting worst by using 
$\ u= \sin{e^{x}} $ because the other term $\ e^{kx} $ is getting bigger and bigger.

I cannot use tabular integration because it is also getting worst. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: substitute $e^x$ by $u$ and notice $e^{2x} dx = u du$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting
$$
u=e^x,
$$
you get using integration by parts:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int e^{2x}\sin(e^x)\,dx&=&\int e^x\sin(e^x)d(e^x)=\int u\sin(u)\,du=-u\cos u+\int \cos u\,du\\
&=&-u\cos u+\sin u+C=-e^x\cos(e^x)+\sin(e^x)+C.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\int e^{2x}\sin(e^x)dx = \int e^x[e^x\sin(e^x)]dx$ and notice that $dv=e^x\sin e^{x}dx \implies v=-\cos(e^x)$.
Take $u$ accordingly to integrate by parts.